# Can lp_solve give bounds if a solution cannot be found within a certain time limit?

Tags: linear-programming, lpsolve

Gurobi can give bounds of the optimal value if it cannot solve a given problem instance within a certain time limit. Can lp_solve do the same?

(Bounds mean an interval in which the optimal value must reside).

Comment: Yes. [This](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/get_mip_gap.htm) is the corresponding function (gap) and I believe [this](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/get_objective.htm) is the best feasible solution.

Comment: @Ioannis Thanks, does the command line interface provide a similar feature?